# Get size of database over a period of time [Postgres]

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a database in postgres and each day more and more data is populated into the db. I would like to write a query which would give me a stat on how my db size has increased. Is there a way to do it?

```
SELECT
    pg_database.datname,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) AS size
    FROM pg_database;
```

The above query gives the current size of the database and not the size over a period of time!

Comment: I see no benefit in recording previous size within the database. If you are running this every day you can compare this result with previous results.

Comment: create a cronjob and save output of your qry